# Linq to Entity Query with Subquery returning error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I've got a Linq to Entity query with a subquery that is returning an error that i'm hoping someone will be able to help me with.

Error Message:

```
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'SmallBusinessManager.Models.TransactionAllocation'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."
```

Linq Query:

```
var query = from transactionSelect in smallBusinessManagerDB.Transaction
        select new
        {
         TransactionId = transactionSelect.TransactionId,
         TransactionNumber = transactionSelect.TransactionNumber,
         Amount = transactionSelect.Amount,
         Balance = (from t2 in smallBusinessManagerDB.TransactionAllocation
                    where t2.InvoiceTransactionId == transactionSelect.TransactionId
                    group t2 by t2.TransactionAllocationId into g
                    select g.Sum(p => p.AllocatedAmount))
};
```

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: Why don't you use a relation?

Comment: Which objects or properties are of type `TransactionAllocation`? It is only the `smallBusinessManagerDB.TransactionAllocation`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = 
    from transactionSelect in smallBusinessManagerDB.Transaction
    select new
    {
        TransactionId = transactionSelect.TransactionId,
        TransactionNumber = transactionSelect.TransactionNumber,
        Amount = transactionSelect.Amount,
        Balance = smallBusinessManagerDB.TransactionAllocation
            .Where(t2 => t2.InvoiceTransactionId == transactionSelect.TransactionId)
            .Sum(p => p.AllocatedAmount)
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex. I made the change, however, the same error occurred.  

    Unable to create a constant value of type 'SmallBusinessManager.Models.TransactionAllocation'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: What happens if you do just `var x = smallBusinessManagerDB.Transaction.ToList()` and `var y = smallBusinessManagerDB.TransactionAllocation.ToList()`?

Comment: x returns as a System.Collection.Generic.List<SmallBusinessManager.Models.Transaction> with all records in the database

y returns as System.Collection.Generic.List<SmallBusinessManager.Models.TransactionAllocation> with all records in the database

Comment: @Chris Nieu - can you take my query, comment Balance setter and check if it works? (Trying to localize this issue)